# Can I restore material from a duplicity backup to another laptop?

Tags: backup, duplicity

I have two laptops. I back both them up to the SAME external hard drive. Backups are labelled laptopA and laptopB. 
A runs 16.04 and
B runs 17.10

Laptop A is no longer working.

I want to 'restore' some files from the laptop A backup to laptop B. However when I specify 'laptopA', as the folder to restore **from**, the backup starts from the folder laptopB.

For clarity, I am working on **laptopB**.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suspect https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DuplicityBackupHowto provides the answer in the "restore" section.  (using the script provided's example, yours just restoring whatever to wherever you want; the example restores a /etc/ file to the /home/user/ directory)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation I think provides your answer

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DuplicityBackupHowto

in it's "Restore" section.  They provide a sample script that restores a file from the /etc/ folder into the /home/user/directory

> "At some point, it may be necessary to restore a file. That task can
>   be accomplished quickly and easily by making minor modifications to
>   the following script:

```
export PASSPHRASE=SomeLongGeneratedHardToCrackKey
export FTP_PASSWORD=WhateverPasswordYouSetUp
duplicity --file-to-restore apt/sources.list ftp://FtpUserID@ftp.domain.com/etc /home/user/sources.list
unset PASSPHRASE
unset FTP_PASSWORD
```

You need to change what you want to restore (apt/sources/list in this example script), and where you want to put it (/home/user/sources.list becomes your "folder B")